# Dog age to human years conversion

Tags: python, type-conversion

I am a beginner at python and one of my practice assignments for class was to create program that converts given dog years to human years within particular parameters that the assignment lists. You will have to look at the attached image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/589CU.png) for the full instructions. Let me know where I went wrong because I'm certain there's a more effective way to write this program and of course, the program I wrote doesn't even work. Don't make anything too complex though because I am a complete beginner.

```
def d_h(dog_age):

    d_age = float(dog_age)
    h = 0
    
    if d_age <= 0:
        return "Age must be a positive number."
        
    if(0 < d_age <= 1):
        h + 15
        return h
    if(1 < d_age <= 2):
        h + 24
        return h
    if(2 < d_age <= 3):
        h + 27.9
        return h
    if(3 < d_age <= 4):
        h + 32
        return h
    if(4 < d_age <= 5):
        h + 36
        return h
    else:
        h + d_age * 7
        return h
            
dog_age = input("What is your dog's age? ")
print("The given dog age, " + str(dog_age) + ", is", str(round(d_h, 2)), "in human years.")
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to reassign value to h like below.
h = h + 1 can also be written as h += 15.

if you use a range in a condition, you would also have to separate upper/lower limits.

```
def d_h(dog_age):

    d_age = float(dog_age)
    h = 0
    
    if d_age <= 0:
        return "Age must be a positive number."
        
    if (0 < d_age) & (d_age <= 1):
        h = h + 15
        return h
```

Answer (score 0):

for the first 5 conditionals ... set `h` the new value with `h = h + 15` or `h += 15`

For the last one you only need to `return d_age * 7`

call the function:

```
str(round(d_h(dog_age), 2))
```